# Text mistakenly indented after ending landscape section

Tags: spacing, indentation

For some reason LaTeX indents the text right after the end of a "landscape" section of my DVI output, even though I don't want it to do so.  Any thoughts on how I can fix this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). It is always best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Personally, I have often solved my own problems in the process of reducing the amount of code actually required to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `\noindent` to prevent indentation.

Answer (score 4):

What is happening is that after the `\end{landscape}` a new paragraph is started. LaTeX adds an indent to the beginning of the paragraph unless you have globally disabled this.

So, you could either add `\noindent` immediately after the `\end{landscape}` (as per @GonzaloMedina's solution), or modify the `\end{landscape}` to always add a `\noindent` for you:

```
\begin{document}

\let\OldEndLandscape\endlandscape
\def\endlandscape{\OldEndLandscape\noindent}

\begin{landscape}
\lipsum[1]
\end{landscape}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

As per the comments, you need to ensure that there is no space after `\end{landscape}`, or use a `%` to terminate any blank lines as in:

```
...
\end{landscape}
   %
\lipsum[2]
```

If you desire an automated solution that enforces no indentation after `\end{landscape}`, perhaps you can use the solution at [Looking for an \ignorespacesandpars](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23100/looking-for-an-ignorespacesandpars).

Comment: But this won't work with "regular" text, since it won't take care of the space after \end{landscape}: an example: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lscape}

\let\OldEndLandscape\endlandscape
\def\endlandscape{\OldEndLandscape\noindent}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
a
\end{landscape}
b\\c
\end{document}` of course, writing `b` in a new line after `\end{landscape}` (which I cannot do here in this comment)

Comment: Good point: I have added that point to the solution.