# Ignore spaces and \par's after an environment

Tags: spacing, environments, paragraphs

In defining an environment, I could use `\ignorespacesafterend` to ignore all spaces after the environment. But how could I also ignore all `\par`s and empty lines after the environment?

In other word, how could I modify the following latex source

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{abc}{\ignorespaces}{\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}

\begin{abc}
One
\end{abc} 
\par
\begin{abc}
Two
\end{abc} 

\begin{abc}
Three
\end{abc}

\end{document}
```

to get the following result?

```
OneTwoThree
```

Comment: take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23100/looking-for-an-ignorespacesandpars

Comment: @dcmst I tried to put `\ignorespacesandallpars` from that answer into my `\newenvironment`, but it failed to remove `\par`s.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to drop the command in at the right place (which is why latex has `\ignorespacesafterend` not just `\ignorespaces`. Also your sample result indicated that you wanted to not only ignore space  after `\end{}` but also *remove* the space already added before that, hence the `\ifhmode\unskip\fi` line. The definition is not quite as in the linked question (I removed the catcode setting)

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{abc}{\ignorespaces}{%
\ifhmode\unskip\fi
\aftergroup\useignorespacesandallpars}

\def\useignorespacesandallpars#1\ignorespaces\fi{%
#1\fi\ignorespacesandallpars}

\makeatletter
\def\ignorespacesandallpars{%
  \@ifnextchar\par
    {\expandafter\ignorespacesandallpars\@gobble}%
    {}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{abc}
One
\end{abc} 
\par
\begin{abc}
Two
\end{abc} 

\begin{abc}
Three
\end{abc}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I try to understand the above code. It seems that `\def\useignorespacesandallpars#1\ignorespaces\fi{#1\fi\ignorespacesandallpars}` is dependent on the definition of the `\end` macro.

Comment: Also, the result is still correct when I remove `\aftergroup`. Why we need `\aftergroup` here?

Comment: @Z.H. actually you don't need `\afergroup`: originally I was going to use `\aftergroup\ignorespacesandallpars` but that wasn't quite the right place either so I added the `\use...` macro (which does as you note depend on the definition of `\end` to explicitly insert it, which means the aftergroup isn't needed (but doesn't do any harm)

Comment: would this work with xparse defined environments as well or would I need to do something different to make that work?  In other words does an xparse defined environment still end with \ignorespaces\fi so the neat trick you used to put the \ignorespacesandallpars still works?  I tried looking at the code but it went through latex3 stuff I couldn't chase down.