# How can I redefine \\ (\tabularcr) such that a space character afterward is ignored?

Tags: tables, tex-core, primitives

Here I append code to `\\` that looks ahead to see whether the `\end` in `\end{tabular}` is up next to bat. This code is hidden within a `\noalign`. The  `\\` has code that looks for a star and then a `[` before finally calling the `\cr`. I suspect that herein lies the problem.

I am not sure whether this applies:

- [Ignore spaces and \par's after an environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179016/ignore-spaces-and-pars-after-an-environment), because `\\` is changed within tabular to fulfil the TeX `\cr` (end of row carriage return).

## Code

See Log Output for `\typeout{\noexpand\reserved@a value: \meaning\reserved@a}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\catcode`@=11 % or \catcode"0040=11 or \makeatletter to change category code of @ to 11 and temporarily to access kernel macro \@tabularcr
\let\clone@tabularcr\@tabularcr%
\def\@tabularcr{\clone@tabularcr \mymidline}%

% Using \hline and \midrule as a model, I made my own hybrid with some extra end of tabular logic
\def\mymidline{%
  \noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi\@aboverulesep=\aboverulesep\global\@belowrulesep=\belowrulesep \futurelet
    \reserved@a\@mymidline}%
\def\@mymidline{\typeout{\noexpand\reserved@a value: \meaning\reserved@a}\ifx\reserved@a\end\else% <-- Here is the value test. I need \reserved@a to eventually equal \end
               \vskip\@aboverulesep%
               \hrule \@height \lightrulewidth%
               \vskip\@belowrulesep%
             \fi
      \ifnum0=`{\fi}}
\catcode`@=12 % or \catcode"0040=12 or \makeatother to restore category code of @ to 12

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
col1 & col2 & col3 \\
\meaning\@tabularcr & col2 & col3 \\
\meaning\\ & col2 & col3 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 \\
\meaning\clone@tabularcr & col2 & col3 \\
\end{tabular}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

## Current Output

[image]

## Desired Output

[image]

Comment: only  difference between your "current" and "desired" images appears to be the final line, how does that relate to your question which asks about white space?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Final line in final row ;)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I will clarify that. I did not mean "white space", rather a technical space in TeX munching terms. See the log output. I  would like the final typeout to yield the definition of `\end`, not "blank space".

Comment: also note that `\@tabularcr` is the wrong macro to patch if `array` package is used (or colortbl, or tabularx or...) You could use `\@ifnextchar` instead of `\futurelet` as the main difference between them is that `\@ifnextchar` skips space but better would be to add your line _after_ `\\ ` has tested and skipped the space, as adding it where you do you stops the `[2pt]` from working.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thx I am aware of the array package changes. You hit the nail on the head with that last part. I'd like to change my code to start testing after the `[2pt]`. I was imitating `\hline` code while trying to hide `\futurelet` in the `\noalign`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as `\\` is anyway skipping over spaces looking for `*` you can let it do the work and ask it if it found a `\end`

this only works for the latex kernel `tabular` although with some name changes could be made for `array` package as well.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\catcode`@=11 % or \catcode"0040=11 or \makeatletter to change category code of @ to 11 and temporarily to access kernel macro \@tabularcr
\def\addmyrule{\noalign{%
           \vskip\@aboverulesep%
           \hrule \@height \lightrulewidth%
           \vskip\@belowrulesep}}

\let\old@xtabularcr\@xtabularcr

\def\@xtabularcr{%
\ifx\@let@token\end\else
\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup
\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup
\aftergroup
\addmyrule
\fi
\old@xtabularcr}

\catcode`@=12 % or \catcode"0040=12 or \makeatother to restore category code of @ to 12

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
col1 & col2 & col3 \\
\meaning\@tabularcr & col2 & col3 \\
\meaning\\ & col2 & col3 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 \\
\meaning\clone@tabularcr & col2 & col3 \\
\end{tabular}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

Comment: Whoa whoa, right when I think i am getting the hang of this you throw another unknown in there. Why is `\@let@token` in there? I assume it is part of the original \\, but why introduce new mechanisms? I am sure you would know why.

Comment: @macmadness86 `\@let@token` is the token used in the `\futurelet` that's inside `\@ifnextchar` so `\\ ` has just tested it to see if it is `*` or `[`  but after  that you can look to see what it was.

Comment: Could you show which `}`s you are skipping over? I can count **2** in `\@ifnextchar [\@argtabularcr {\ifnum 0=‘{\fi }\cr }` and **1** in  the expanded `\@argtabularcr`: `\ifnum 0=‘{\fi }\ifdim #1>\z@ \unskip \@xargarraycr {#1}\else \@yargarraycr {#1}\fi `. Am I right that you are skip those? This would mean `f(3) n^2-1= x` where x is the number of `\aftergroup`s. So for the `array` package, I'd have to count them just like you did here, except in a redefinition of `\@xarraycr`.

Comment: @macmadness86 probably. (I just guessed, to be honest:-) initially I wrote 3 but it appeared too early so I did 7:-) I could analyse it exactly but not just now...

Comment: Haha ok! Well, with `array` loaded, it is **3**. But then with `arydshln` loaded on top of that, it jumps back up to **7**, because the `\cr` is replaced with `\adl@cr`, which expands to another `}`: `\noalign {\adl@@cr \z@ }`. This leads me to suspect that using the \\ mechanism may be more trouble than it is worth (or maybe this annoyance is commonplace in the development of LaTeX)