# How can I ensure that an environment always starts on a new line? (a new paragraph / horizontal box)?

Tags: environments

Sometimes when creating environments, you want to ensure that they always

- start new paragraph when two environments appear immediately after one another
- eat up spaces
- generally idiot-proof (which, dare I say, might also be called "fully LaTeX compatible")

I have seen a few techniques. Are there any recommended ways of doing this to avoid trouble?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{test}
  {\par\noindent}% <-- before env hook
  {}% <-- after env hook

\begin{document}
\begin{test}
\fbox{\parbox{\linewidth}{\lipsum[1]}}
\end{test}
\begin{test}
\fbox{\parbox{\linewidth}{\lipsum[1]}}
\end{test}

\begin{test}
\fbox{\parbox{\linewidth}{\lipsum[1]}}
\end{test}
\end{document}
```

## Ideal Environment

This one can handle `\begin{test}\end{test}\begin{test}\end{test}` back to back. I used `\par\noindent` in the before environment hook. Is this the *right* way to do this? Based on this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22853/13552, it seems that I would also need `\leavevmode`. Could somebody clarify this and any other tips that are "good practice".
[image]

## Without Auto-new paragraphs (`\par` in before hook), without `\noindent`

[image]

## Without Auto-new paragraphs (`\par` in before hook), with `\noindent`

[image]

## Related

- [Ignore spaces and \par's after an environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179016/ignore-spaces-and-pars-after-an-environment)
- [Looking for an \ignorespacesandpars](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23100/looking-for-an-ignorespacesandpars)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want that the environment starts a new paragraph with no indentation and also ignores spaces after it,

```
\newenvironment{test}
 {\par\noindent\ignorespaces}
 {\ignorespacesafterend}
```

The missing `\ignorespaces` is the cause for the small spaces in the third example. This happens because `\noindent` starts a new paragraph (note that `\par` only *ends* a paragraph) and so the space after `\begin{test}` (generated by the end-of-line) is not ignored.

Comment: Would you care to comment on `\leavevmode` as explained in the linked answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22852/function-and-usage-of-leavevmode/22853#22853?

Comment: @JonathanKomar There's no need for `\leavevmode`; that answer deals with a completely different situation.

Answer (score 11):

It is almost always best to avoid starting horizontal mode in the begin code of the environment, so do not use `\noindent` or `\leavevmode` etc.

The usual way is as a trivlist, the exact parameters of which can be customised, and this is how `center` `quote` `verbatim` etc work.

Note your test file makes overfull lines as the fbox adds space around a parbox that is already full width.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{test}
  {\trivlist{}\item\relax}% <-- before env hook
  {\endtrivlist}% <-- after env hook

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{test}
\fbox{\parbox{\linewidth}{\lipsum[1]}}
\end{test}
\begin{test}
\fbox{\parbox{\linewidth}{\lipsum[1]}}
\end{test}

\begin{test}
\fbox{\parbox{\linewidth}{\lipsum[1]}}
\end{test}
\end{document}
```

---

To see one (of many) disadvantages to starting hmode in the environment definition try a test such as

```
\begin{test}

\fbox{\parbox{\linewidth}{\lipsum[1]}}
\end{test}
```

with the definition here and compare with other definitions. 
Environments that start a paragraph ought to silently accept the environment content starting with a paragraph break.

Comment: (I will probably delete as this is a bit off-topic): can you check https://gist.github.com/jfbu/2f3d04414359f716f98ea64dac91eb0e

Comment: sorry I meant to add "please" but I hit return key too early and also I wanted to say I have other examples with minipage embedded in an environment when the minipage is fullwidth and the environement doesn't do ignorespacesafterend

Comment: @jfbu shouldn't need ignorespacesafterend here (I would if I had used `\begin{trivlist} \end{trivlist}`

Comment: I have added a comment at the gist place (I don't know if the ``@davidcarlisle`` pings you there). About this ignorespacesafterend, not sure we are talking about same thing so I put it into new gist. Here is what I mean: https://gist.github.com/jfbu/87e5bcfcc64c4199a942be1d5d51c608

Comment: @ShreevatsaR thanks, tricky language, English, it seems:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle :-)

Comment: (I have added comments at the two gists above, but as pinging from gist does not work, I have been pulling you there into not very convenient way to chat -- just mentioning here my last updates, then I will not harass you anymore ;-) )

Comment: Relevant here about `\trivlist`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47069/13552